# Thorax.js collection view does not render model attributes

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, thorax.js

I'm trying to get a basic web app working using thorax.js and am encountering some difficulties getting collection views to render.

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn3N8/

From the fiddle, here's my collection view for testing:

```
{{#collection tag="ul"}}
<li> {{name}}
{{/collection}}
```

and here's the JS code I use to tell thorax to use this view:

```
var view = new Thorax.View({
  collection: new Thorax.Collection([
    {name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]),
  name: 'coll'
});
```

The main problem is that the items in the collection view appears to render---i.e., if I render a collection using a `<ul>`, the correct number of `<li>` DOM elements appear---but none of the attributes within each collection model are rendered!

My guess is that I'm just going about doing this in a way that thorax doesn't understand ... but it's hard to tell from the docs and whatnot that are out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, it's because you're not closing your `<li>` tags. I can't tell you exactly why this is the case, but if I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that Thorax has to bind the children of a CollectionView to a DOM element, and there isn't a clear choice without the closing tag. That's probably a weak guess without looking at the source (which isn't quite as friendly to read IMHO as Backbone is), but closing your `<li>` tags does solve the problem.

Comment: That's just what I found, too. I was a bit surprised because in my understanding `<li>` tags don't require closing in HTML5 ... but I can see how it'd be a problem. Closing the tags does fix things though.

Comment: yeah, my hunch is that it's not a standards problem, but a Thorax problem... confirming that the problem's in Thorax, though, might be a lengthy expedition.